# Geoserver Web Cache using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geoserver

I am using python to cache geoserver layers by using GeoWebCache and I am new in this.
Here is my code which I am trying to use for GeoWebCache:

```
import json
import urllib3
import base64

un = '*****'
pw = '******'

baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/"

def seedLayer(layer):
    print ('seeding: ' + layer)
    url = baseURL + layer + '.json'
    r = urllib3.PoolManager()
    baseString = base64.encodebytes(('%s:%s' % (un, pw)).encode())
    base64string = baseString.decode().replace('\n', '')
    data = {'seedRequest':{'minX':[],'minY':[],'maxX':[],'maxY':[],'gridSetId':'Leaflet 
    3857','zoomStart':00,'zoomStop':18,'format':'image/png','type':'seed','threadCount':2}}
    encoded_data = json.dumps(data)
    request = r.request(
                'POST',
                url,
                body=encoded_data,
                headers={'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base64string,'Content-Type': 
                'application/json'})
    #request.headers("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    #request.headers('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    request.data
    #req = r.urlopen(request)
    req = r.urlopen(request)

seedLayer('Test:SHA_1')
```

Refer to this example: https://gist.github.com/alexgleith/844146bb24b4f22d856e

When running this code i got the below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "D:\Python\webCache.py", line 30, in 
>           seedLayer('Test:SHA_1')
>         File "D:\Python\webCache.py", line 28, in seedLayer
>           req = r.urlopen(request)
>       TypeError: urlopen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The linked gist is using `urllib2`, while you're using `urllib3`. The API has changed: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.3/managers.html

Comment: @rdas Thank you for the reply. I have changed the code according to urllib3 which is python 3.x library.

Comment: Code written for `urllib2` won't work for `urllib3` - so you need to make more changes to make it work. Check the linked documentation.

Comment: @rdas I have made all the possible changes but I have no idea what to add in r.openurl().

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.3/managers.html